# iTunes connect mixing screenshots

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have two langs on iTunes Connect. After I upload all my screenshots and pressed "Save" button they became mixed. E.g. first en, second ru, third en, fourth ru, etc.
Does anybody know how to fix this problem or may be it's an apple server side bug?

Comment: Have you tried to drag with the mouse the image with the correct order?

Comment: @Lorenzo Order is ok, but after save button pressed all goes bad - they become mixed by localization.

Comment: I'm trying also with my iTunesConnect

Comment: I have problem to see my iTunesConnect. I changed the order of my images but when save all is blocked... the page is not refreshed.. I think there is something wrong in the site at the moment

Comment: No... now it works.. and the order is correctly saved. I used Internet explorer. Which browser are you using?

Comment: @Lorenzo I use Safari, Chrome. Do you have more than one localization & screenshots for it? Hm, now I try deliver ruby app, but result is wrong too. iTunes saves order of screenshots but mixing screenshots between localizations.

Comment: I have more localizations but not for the images. Try with IE to see if you have the same problem. Normally I use Safari but at the moment I'm usng a different PC